# Generate plots from for loop with non-standard evaluation

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I am trying to generate plots from a for-loop using `ggplot` in `R`.

Let's create a dataset:

```
# Libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Set seed
set.seed(123)

# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(
  time = c( rep(1,20), rep(2, 20), rep(3, 20) ), 
  value_a =c(rnorm(n = 60, mean = 50, sd = 10)),
  value_b =c(rnorm(n = 60, mean = 50, sd = 10)),
  value_c =c(rnorm(n = 60, mean = 50, sd = 10))
)
```

I can generate a plot using `ggplot`.

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x = time, y = value_a), position = position_jitter(width = 0.1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100))
```

[image]

Next, I would like to generate these plots for every column of the data frame (with time on the x-axis and value_n on the y-axis). I thought a for loop would do the trick:

```
for(i in colnames(df)[-1]){
  print(
    ggplot(df_a, aes(x= time, y = i)) +
      geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=0.1)) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100))
  )
}
```

It provides the following error:

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

The error arises because the `i` from the for loop is seen as a character vector, and I can (logically) not provide a continuous scale to a discrete value.

Reproduction of the error outside the for-loop:

```
ggplot(df_a, aes(x= time, y = "value_a")) + # value_a is provided as character vector
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=0.1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100))
```

**Question**

Is there a way to prevent 'value_a' to be interpreted as a character vector, so that I will be able to control the scale in the loop? Or is there another way to conveniently generate plots from different columns in dataframe?

Comment: I would `melt` and use facets - this is more `ggplot2` way

Comment: Hey user213544, to expand on @PoGibas's comments, you melt (or pivot_longer() ) df, then just subset for value_a, value_b ...

Comment: like this for example: df %>% pivot_longer(-time) %>% filter(name=="value_a") %>% ggplot()+geom_jitter(aes(x=time,y=value))

Comment: I've modified the title to make it better searchable - hope this fits your idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with PoGibas's comment - reshaping to long format and using `facet` is likely the better way to go. However, If you need it for creating different plots/images etc, use `eval(sym(i))` instead, like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Set seed
set.seed(123)

# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(
  time = c( rep(1,20), rep(2, 20), rep(3, 20) ), 
  value_a =c(rnorm(n = 60, mean = 50, sd = 10)),
  value_b =c(rnorm(n = 60, mean = 50, sd = 10)),
  value_c =c(rnorm(n = 60, mean = 50, sd = 10))
)

for(i in colnames(df)[-1]){
  print(
    ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x= time, y = eval(sym(i)))) +
      geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=0.1)) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100)) +
      labs(y = i) #added automatic y-label 

  )
}
```

[image][image][image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>